# How can I successfully loop through an array of classes in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to pass an array of classes holding a comment each into a function that will display all the comments in a list. The purpose of the function is to make the list drop down down with an animated feel to it. Slightly different to use .slideDown and very similar to google+'s way of showing all comments of a post.

Here is a JSFiddle link from one of my other questions. This what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/MZzUr/9/

Here is my attempt to do the same thing but using an array of classes holding the comments instead of a for loop:

http://jsfiddle.net/A9WLc/4/

Don't intend to give up on this.. been at it for days now.
Thanks in advance.
Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are going for. This isn't exactly it but it might be useful: http://jsfiddle.net/xkfqN/19/

I have tried to recreate how google does their animation for a social network I worked on but gave up and just went with the way facebook does it...it just pops :) I don't know what kind of voodoo magic google does but it is really hard to replicate.

Comment: Thanks, yea I've been tried to replicate it for days but struggled and confused myself more. The person who created the first JSFiddle link in my question got really close but I couldn't translate that code to a state where it would work with my application. Is it possible for you to achieve that same effect you have in your code but sliding back up too? I tried slideToggle/toggle it doesn't go up the same way it goes down.

Comment: I think I've spent enough time trying to do this. Your code is good enough for me to move forward with. Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. It's really close to what the google+ one does. Thanks for the comments also as they'll make the code easier for me to understand.

Comment: Yeah, let me know if anything isn't clear. I cleaned up some needless code and added comments here: http://jsfiddle.net/xkfqN/47/

Comment: Yep all the code is clear. I understand it 100%. Thanks for your help. Marked you up.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `items[0]` it returns the DOM node, not a jQuery object. It is equivalent of using [`.get(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).  You want to use [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) which returns the jQuery object.

```
var myItem = items.eq(0);
var height = myItem.height();
myItem.hide();
```